# I have a managed DLL and a managed program in C# - I want the managed DLL to be inside the assembly and not external

Tags: c#, dll, managed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to merge a DLL into a .NET EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631567/possible-to-merge-a-dll-into-a-net-exe)

I have a C# program that uses 2 managed DLLs.
I wish that on the client computer I will not have to include both DLLs - but they will be inside the assembly itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx).