# Creating a standalone .exe for a windows application in visual studio 2008?

Tags: windows, installation, exe

I have created a windows based application in C# using visual studio 2008 which basically scans for the registry and then fixes the resulting errors. Now using the msi installer i have made a setup and it works fine. However i have met with a new requirement.

Usually after providing the setup to the user/client has to install the setup and when installed, in the installed folder there are lots of .dlls that i had used to create the project. But my requirememt is to create a single standalone .exe using which i wouldnt have to provide my users with the setup file. All i need to do is that using this single .exe file my whole project should execute and perform the same process of scanning and fixing the registry.

I also tried "ClickOnce Deployment in .NET Framework 2.0" and got the error "ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator'". and also have gone through the link 
["ClickOnce does not support the request execution level 'requireAdministrator.'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023998/clickonce-does-not-support-the-request-execution-level-requireadministrator)

But still i feel that i would be comfortable if i can get a single standalone exe which can execute my windows forms application.

Is there any way to do it?

Any hint with this thing will be really helpful to me.

Thanks in advance

~Viknesh

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631567/possible-to-merge-a-dll-into-a-net-exe - this should help