# How to set platform for mscorlib.dll for dll merging.?

Tags: c#, dll, c#-3.0, .net-assembly

I have a task of merging multiple native as well as third party dll's inside a single exe for easy distribution.

I had tried ClickOnce method from the Visual studio 9.0. But in vain, referred [Creating a standalone .exe for a windows application in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759142/creating-a-standalone-exe-for-a-windows-application-in-visual-studio-2008/12759191#12759191) for my query but still couldnt get any proper results.

I also tried some third party tools as suggested in [Embedding DLLs in a compiled executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189549/embedding-dlls-in-a-compiled-executable) and [Possible to merge a DLL into a .NET EXE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631567/possible-to-merge-a-dll-into-a-net-exe) but still in vain.

The third party tools that i used for dll merging are SmartAssembly and Boxedapp Packer both are good. In SmartAssembly after merging the dlls inside a single .exe i get some excemptions. So i dont know how to go through. Also Il Merge looks good but im using 13 native as well as third party dlls for my project and im not able to get any proper reference materials to work with IL Merge which is totally command line. It would be good if i can get any proper tutorials for using IL Merge.

Also recently i used IL Merger Tool from microsoft, this tool looks good and the documentation is here http://ilmergertool.codeplex.com/documentation. I have did eveything but when i click the "Begin Merge" button i get a message saying "Merging Failed. For details please check log file". And when i check the log file i found this

"Set platform to 'v2', using directory 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727' for mscorlib.dll"

Im not sure what to do with this. So any suggestions would be helpful.

Also it would be nice if i can get suggestions for some Tools or SDK's that are used to merge assemblies and dll's. Im sure there are lots of them.

So far i have tried SmartAssembly and BoxedAPP packer.

Thanks

-Vikneshwar

Comment: You can't merge assemblies containing native code.  You should use another merge, the kind that produces a program named setup.exe.  Create an installer.  Very simple to do with a Setup project.

Comment: Apart from the native code is it possible to merge dll inside a single exe. I have tried many things but havent found anything suitable.